# Can I use "grand grand grand father"?

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "grand grand grand father" to indicate my father's father's grand father?

If it is eligible, is it grammatically correct? I mean there are three consecutive adjective without comma to separate. Or it's ungrammatical but still usable?

Comment: Great-great-grandfather would be preferred

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In English the expression for your grandfather's father is "**great**-grandfather".  Your great-grandfather's father would be your "**great-great**-grandfather".  And so on.

Generally we don't use more than two "greats", but sometimes people will say something like "*my great-great-great-great-great-(etc.)-grandparents*" to mean their *ancestors*.  You don't have to be exact, although you can be if you actually know your exact family history.

Comment: I've also heard used "third-great grandfather" for  your great-great-grandfather's father.

Comment: @BLT I've never heard that, but it might be used somewhere outside my experience.

Comment: I still wouldn't say it's common, and it might not be understood everywhere, then. Good to know.